# How do I make a 3D cursor that follows the mouse in Godot?

Tags: godot, mouse, godot-4

I want to position a 3D object at my mouse cursor. How can I do that in Godot? In Unity, I'd use
[`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html).

Answer (score 3):

[`Camera3D.project_position`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_camera3d.html#class-camera3d-method-project-position) is the Godot equivalent function.

Here's an implementation that can either move the position with fixed
orientation or can also point the cursor object. I'm using `_g` to indicate
which values are in worldspace (global) to avoid confusion with localspace.

```
extends Node3D

@onready var camera := get_parent() as Camera3D
@export_range(1, 1000) var depth := 10.0
@export var should_only_set_position := false

func _process(_dt):
    var mouse_pos = get_viewport().get_mouse_position()
    var cursor_pos_g = camera.project_position(mouse_pos, depth)

    if should_only_set_position:
        # To just position it, set global_position and set the desired
        # orientation in your scene.
        global_position = cursor_pos_g

    else:
        # To make the cursor point at the centre of the screen, ensure it faces
        # -z direction.
        var cam_forward_g = -camera.get_global_transform().basis.z
        var look_pos_g = camera.global_position + cam_forward_g * depth * 1.5
        look_at_from_position(cursor_pos_g, look_pos_g)
```

Since Godot's [forward direction is -z](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_vector3.html#class-vector3-constant-forward) (?!), you need to point your cursor along the -z axis for it to be oriented correctly. (Notice `cam_forward_g` is also -z.) If you have trouble, add some extra arms to make the orientation changes very obvious.

[image: animation showing the cursor following the mouse and pointing at the centre]

Cursor has the above script and it has some shapes underneath it to make it visible:

[image: Hierarchy in the cursor scene]

I put it under the camera, but you could also a export to let it live anywhere: `@export var camera : Camera3D` instead.

[image: Hierarchy in the main scene]

You could also change this code to make `look_pos_g` the global position of an object you're going to interact with or your player character.